# c++ improve vector sorting by presorting with old vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a a vector of pair with the following typdef

```
typedef std::pair<double, int> myPairType;
typedef std::vector<myPairType> myVectorType;
myVectorType myVector;
```

I fill this vector with `double` values and the `int` part of the pair is an index. 
The vector then looks like this

```
0.6594 1
0.5434 2
0.5245 3
0.8431 4
...
```

My program has a number of time steps with slight variations in the `double` values and every time step I sort this vector with `std::sort` to something like this.

```
0.5245 3
0.5434 2
0.6594 1
0.8431 4
```

The idea is now to somehow use the vector from the last time step (the "old vector, already sorted) to presort the current vector (the new vector, not yet sorted). And use an insertions sort or tim sort to sort the "rest" of the then presorted vector.

Is this somehow possible? I couldn't find a function to order the "new" vector of pairs by one part (the `int` part). 
And if it is possible could this be faster then sorting the whole unsorted "new" vector?

Thanks for any pointers into the right direction.

tiom

**UPDATE**

First of all thanks for all the suggestions and code examples. I will have a look at each of them and do some benchmarking if they will speed up the process.

Since there where some questions regarding the vectors I will try to explain in more detail what I want to accomplish.

As I said I have a number if time steps `1` to `n`. For every time step I have a vector of `double` data values with approximately 260000 elements.

In every time step I add an index to this vector which will result in a vector of pairs `<double, int>`. See the following code snippet.

```
typedef typename myVectorType::iterator myVectorTypeIterator; // iterator for myVector
std::vector<double> vectorData; // holds the double data values
myVectorType myVector(vectorData.size()); // vector of pairs <double, int>

myVectorTypeIterator myVectorIter = myVector.begin();
// generating of the index
for (int i = 0; i < vectorData.size(); ++i) {
    myVectorIter->first = vectorData[i];
    myVectorIter->second = i;
    ++myVectorIter;
}

std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end() );
```

(The index is 0 based. Sorry for my initial mistake in the example above)
I do this for every time step and then sort this vector of pairs with `std::sort`.

The idea was now to use the sorted vector of pairs  of time step `j-1` (lets call it `vectorOld`) in time step `j` as a "presorter" for the "new" `myVector` since I assume the ordering of the sorted "new" `myVector` of time step `j` will only differ in some cases from the already sorted `vectorOld` of time step `j-1`.

With "presorter" I mean to rearrange the pairs in the "new" `myVector` into a vector `presortedVector` of type `myVectorType`  by the same index order as the `vectorOld` and then let a tim sort or some similar sorting algorithm that is good in presorted date do the rest of the sorting.

Some data examples: 
This is what the beginning of `myVector` looks like in time step `j-1` before the sorting.

```
0.0688015 0
0.0832928 1
0.0482259 2
0.142874 3
0.314859 4
0.332909 5
...
```

And after the sorting

```
0.000102207 23836
0.000107378 256594
0.00010781 51300
0.000109315 95454
0.000109792 102172
...
```

So I in the next time step `j` this is my `vectorOld` and I  like to take the element with index `23836` of the "new" `myVector` and put it in the first place of the `presortedVector`, element with index `256594` should be the second element in `presortedVector` and so on. But the elements have to keep their original index. So `256594` will not be index `0` but only element 0 in `presortedVector` still with index `256594`

I hope this is a better explanation of my plan.

Comment: A std::vector is not suitable for insertions sort

Comment: How many values do you have to sort ? Do you append new values ? Another approach is to use an std::set, but you should benchmark your code. Resorting the vector could be faster than using a std::set if the number of values is not too big.

Comment: I have around 260000 pairs in the vector. Is this to much for the mentioned `std:set`? Ah yes and new values are not appended.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "old vector". Do you have two similar vectors, one that is sorted and another that is almost sorted? Or you just have one vector which is sorted initially, then have a small number of local changes applied to it?

Comment: I have a number of timesteps. Each timestep has the same number of datapoints as double values (arround 260000). Now in each timestep I load the datapoints into the `double` part of the vector, generate the index (`int` part of the vector) and sort this vector with `std::sort()`. The idea was now to use the already sorted vector from timestep 0 (vector0) to "presort" the vector from timestep 1 (vector1) by reordering the vector1 with the index of vector0 and use a sorting function like tim sort to sort the "rest" of the vector. I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: So vector0 is not a complete subset of vector1? There are values both added and removed? In that case I don't think you can do better than re-sorting the whole vector.

Comment: So the new vector is a completely unsorted version of the old vector, plus some changes on top, right?

Answer (score 1):

First, scan through the sequence to find the first element that's smaller than the preceding one (either a loop, or C++11's [`std::is_sorted_until`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until)). This is the start of the unsorted portion. Use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) on the remainder, then merge the two halves with [`std::inplace_merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge).

```
template<class RandomIt, class Compare>
void sort_new_elements(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp)
{
    RandomIt mid = std::is_sorted_until(first, last, comp);
    std::sort(mid, last, comp);
    std::inplace_merge(first, mid, last, comp);
}
```

This should be more efficient than sorting the whole sequence indiscriminately, as long as the presorted sequence at the front is significantly larger than the unsorted part.

Comment: There's a [`std::is_sorted_until`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until) algorithm to perform the scan.

Comment: @Blastfurnace thanks, there are obviously still parts of C++11 that I haven't discovered yet.

Comment: I think this is the base idea of [natural merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort). One could expand this into limiting from the end of container, and natrually continuing, derive a set of intervals with proper ordering, and then merge them together, which would be it IMO. Btw I let myself include your method (with attribution ofc) in my answer which is an attempt of complete solution the problem, including preparation of new vector according to sort order of old values.

Answer (score 0):

Using the sorted vector would likely result in *more* comparisons (just to find a matching item).

What you seem to be looking for is a self-ordering container.

You could use a set (and remove/re-insert on modification).

Alternatively you could use Boost Multi Index which affords a bit more convenience (e.g. use a struct instead of the pair)

Comment: Why would you find matching items, when you can simply iterate once over the "old" vector and take index in the "new" vector from it. This is possible to do in `O(n)` (`2n` specifically) for optimistic cases. And reinserting modified values would be troublesome. How would you identify a value for reinsertion when it's a `double`?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this could be faster than sorting the whole unsorted "new" vector. It will depend on the data.

But this will create a sorted copy of a new vector based on the order of an old vector:

```
myVectorType getSorted(const myVectorType& unsorted, const myVectorType& old) {
  myVectorType sorted(unsorted.size());

  auto matching_value 
    = [&unsorted](const myPairType& value)
    { return unsorted[value.second - 1]; };

  std::transform(old.begin(), old.end(), sorted.begin(), matching_value);
  return sorted;
}
```

You will then need to "finish" sorting this vector. I don't know how much quicker (if at all) this will be than sorting it from scratch.

[Live demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/609e48160fb0012a)

Comment: Hi I tried to get your function into my code to do some benchmarking. However it only works for 1 timestep.  I have now something like 
if (timestep >= 1 ) {
  vector_presorted = getSorted(vector_pair_new, vector_pair_old); 
  std::sort(vector_presorted.begin(), vector_presorted.end() );
  vector_pair_old = vector_presorted;
}
else{
  std::sort(vector_pair_new.begin(), vector_pair_new.end() );
  vector_pair_old = vector_pair_new;
}
But this breaks at timstep 2 with Segmentation in the matching_value line.

Comment: My lambda function does no bounds checking of `unsorted` so you need to be sure that the indexes in the old vector are not out of the bounds of the `unsorted` vector. I'm assuming a 1-based index based on your example.

Comment: I've added a link to a live demo to demonstrate it working over multiple timesteps. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create new vector with the order of the old and then use algorithms that has good complexity for (nearly) sorted inputs for the restoration of order.

Below I put an example of how it works, with [Mark's function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28813905/1133179) as `restore_order`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

typedef std::pair<double, int> myPairType;
typedef std::vector<myPairType> myVectorType;

void outputMV(const myVectorType& vect, std::ostream& out)
{
    for(const auto& element : vect) 
        out << element.first << " " << element.second << '\n';
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/a/28813905/1133179
template<class RandomIt, class Compare>
void restore_order(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp)
{
    RandomIt mid = std::is_sorted_until(first, last, comp);
    std::sort(mid, last, comp);
    std::inplace_merge(first, mid, last, comp);
}

int main() {
    myVectorType myVector = {{3.5,0},{1.4,1},{2.5,2},{1.0,3}};
    myVectorType mv2 = {{3.6,0},{1.35,1},{2.6,2},{1.36,3}};
    auto comparer = [] (const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { return lhs.first < rhs.first;};

    // make sure we didn't mess with the initial indexing
    int i = 0;
    for(auto& element : myVector) element.second = i++;
    i = 0;
    for(auto& element : mv2) element.second = i++;

    //sort the initial vector
    std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), comparer);
    outputMV(myVector, cout);

    // this will replace each element of myVector with a corresponding  
    // value from mv2 using the old sorted order
    std::for_each(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(),
       [mv2] (auto& el) {el = mv2[el.second];}
    );

    // restore order in case it was different for the new vector
    restore_order(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), comparer);
    outputMV(myVector, cout);
    return 0;
}
```

This works in `O(n)` up to the point of restore then. Then the trick is to use good function for it. A nice candidate will have good complexity for nearly sorted inputs. I used function that [Mark Ransom posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28813905/1133179), which works, but still isn't perfect.

It could get outperformed by bubble sort inspired method. Something like, iterate over each element, if the order between `current` and `next` element is wrong recursively swap `current` and `next`. However there is a bet on how much the order changes - if the order doesn't vary much you will stay close to `O(2n)`, if does - you will go up to `O(n^2)`.

I think the best would be an implementation of [natural merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort). That has best case (sorted input) `O(n)`, and worst `O(n log n)`.